# Why does index cause typeerror in pandas dataframe groupby agg method?

Tags: python, pandas, typeerror

I'm building an aggregate with the following code:

```
import numpy
import pandas

orders = pandas.read_csv(
    "orders.csv",
    dtype={
        "order_id": numpy.int32,
        "user_id": numpy.int32,
        "eval_set": "category",
        "order_number": numpy.int8,
        "order_dow": numpy.int8,
        "order_hour_of_day": numpy.int8,
        "days_since_prior_order": numpy.float64
    }
)

orders.set_index('order_id', inplace=True, drop=False)

prior_order_products = pandas.read_csv(
    "order_products__prior.csv",
    dtype={
        "order_id": numpy.int32,
        "product_id": numpy.int32,
        "add_to_cart_order": numpy.int16,
        "reordered": numpy.int8
    }
)

prior_order_products.set_index(['order_id', 'product_id'], inplace=True, drop=False)

prior_order_products = prior_order_products.join(orders, how="inner", on='order_id', rsuffix='_')
prior_order_products.drop('order_id_', inplace=True, axis=1)

del orders

prior_order_products['user_product_id'] =\
    100000 * prior_order_products["user_id"].astype(numpy.int64) + prior_order_products["product_id"]

user_products = prior_order_products.\
    groupby('user_product_id', sort=False).\
    agg({'order_id': ['size', 'last'], 'add_to_cart_order': 'sum'})
```

It gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Strategy/PycharmProjects/Test/Main.py", line 52, in <module>
    agg({'order_id': ['size', 'last'], 'add_to_cart_order': 'sum'})
  ...
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'str'
```

I can get the error away if I comment the line

```
prior_order_products.set_index(['order_id', 'product_id'], inplace=True, drop=False)
```

Also, I can get the error away if I limit number of rows read into `prior_order_products`. The file is not malformed, no data is missing or wrong format.

What does the error really mean? How is it related to index on `prior_order_products`? How is it related to number of rows in `prior_order_products`?

Comment: Can you share a small snippet of what your data looks like?

Comment: @user666 You can get all data [here](https://www.instacart.com/datasets/grocery-shopping-2017)